# Fragile usage ( for peoples )

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning

When and how to use word "fragile" for people like

> He is fragile.

Please explain with examples.

Answer (score 1):

A *'fragile person'* can mean either of two things.

1. **A fragile person (Physically)**

This refers to the stature of a particular person. A person who is not physically fit is usually referred to as a *'fragile person'*. This maybe due to an illness or simply because he is very thin or unhealthy.

**Note**: This is hardly used. People usually use *'weak'* instead of *'fragile'*.

Example: *He is a very fragile man. One punch and you might break multiple bones.*

2. **A fragile person (Emotionally)**

An emotionally fragile person is generally incapable of hiding is emotions and can be hurt very easily. He may not accept criticism or any verbal puns intended at him and may lead to an emotionally imbalanced state (such as crying). They may or may not be a weak-willed person also. Some people are emotional fragile all the time, and other people are just emotionally fragile when they are going through really hard times, when they feel like they cannot take anymore stress, being this fragile, could cause a nervous break down. It also can be used to somebody who gets offended very easily.

Example: *He's very fragile ever since the break-up.*

Answer (score 0):

For elderly people it is common to use [frail](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/american/frail):

> 2)slender and delicate; not robust; weak